# How to fix double response from node side socket.io?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I try to make a simple chat application with react.js, socket.io and node.js. Every thing is good, but when I send message every iteration I'll have next response:

```
message: 'Hi' id: 1 
------------------------
message: 'Hi' id: 1 
message: 'how are you' id:2
message: 'how are you' id:2
-----------------------------
message: 'Hi' id: 1
message: 'how are you' id:2
message: 'how are you' id:2
message: 'th. How are you?' id:3
message: 'th. How are you?' id:3
message: 'th. How are you?' id:3
-----------------------------------
```

Can you help me fix this bug?
you can find full code here: https://github.com/zhurbeyaleksander/second-chat

```
  sendMessage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    socket.emit(this.state.chatName, this.state);
    socket.on('girls', (msg) => {

     console.log(msg.message.message)

   });
  }
```

Comment: Post more code. This is happing because the sendMessage() function is called more than once.

Comment: all my code here: https://github.com/zhurbeyaleksander/second-chat